what if a granted claim is invalidated for being too broad?
Suppose that a claim defines a component that must satisfy at least one of three conditions, A, B, and C.
This claim is granted.
Someone later tries to invalid this claim through PTAB.
The court finds that the claim is too broad, and that it is obvious for the component to satisfy condition A.
Question:

In this event, is the entire claim invalided, or can it be modified to remove condition A?


If a claim is too broad with conditions A, B and C, how does making it broader by removing A make it more acceptable?

The component has to satisfy conditions A, B, and/or C in order to infringe. So If condition A is removed, then implementations where the component satisfies condition A would NOT infringe.

But the question is about being overly broad, not infringement.

so removing condition A actually narrows it? So basically with less conditions, the component is narrower?

No, removing a condition broadens a claim. Say I patent a battery containing element A, B and C. A claim of a battery containing only B and C covers every battery also containing A as well as ones only containing B and C. The more conditions in a claim, the narrower it becomes.

There is only one component. A component must satisfy any of three conditions in order to be considered the component protected in the claim. So the more conditions, the broader the claim?

No, exactly the opposite. Say I have a claim for a battery that uses lithium and cobalt. You need both elements to infringe it. If a different patent has a claim requiring only lithium it covers batteries with lithium and  batteries with lithium and cobalt. Thus broader. Long complicated claims are narrower than short simple claims as a rule.

Now is you had a claim which required A or B or C than it gets broader with more conditions. But not with "ands". A list of elements with commas and "and" require all the elements to be present to be infringed.

Right, it is an "OR" condition. satisfy at least one of three conditions, A, B, and C.

That is clearer. In any case I am not a lawyer and I never answer questions about claim language since that is practicing law in my opinion.


The court finds that the claim is too broad, ...

"Overbreadth" is not a specific reason for rejection/invalidation. The court can invalidate claims in many ways (in your example obviousness) but breadth per se is not one of them.

In this event, is the entire claim invalided, or can it be modified to remove condition A?

AFAIK, it is possible to amend, but it will be much less expensive to have a proper claim drafted the first time around. There are also ways to file new claims if continuations are kept going the whole time.
Avoid using OR in claims. Such claims are typically very easy to design around by substituting an element that wasn't recited. Try instead to express elements generically and put the individual incarnations in dependent claims if appropriate.
